# Why does Bootstrap 5 not style datalists?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, html-datalist

For a form, I would like to use the HTML5 datalist option so that I can provide a list of terms that will be suggested to the user for autocompletion - but entering another value than the suggested ones is also possible.

I found that while bootstrap 5 styles all the normal dropdowns and select options without a problem, the datalist is not affected at all and is displayed as a small and ugly text box instead.
Moreover, it is not even mentioned in the documentation, as if this kind of form tag would not exist at all.

Is there no way to style datalists with bootstrap?

[Datalist dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbRTd.jpg)
[Bootstrap dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l53G.jpg)

I tried to give the datalist the form-select class, but this will make it appear as a seperate, not-clickable field (styled, however...).
Even when I give normal style attributes to the datalist option (like font-weight: or whatever) this will not result in any changes.

[Datalist dropdown with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGYtr.jpg)

So...how can I style datalists?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/form-control/#datalists "These are similar to <select> elements, but come with more menu styling limitations and differences. While most browsers and operating systems include some support for <datalist> elements, their styling is inconsistent at best."

Comment: So basically, the answer is "don't"?